# JQuery list item, set the list value for input field when user click the list item respectively

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have a two input text fields. I need to pass the value from the dynamic list items when a user clicks it respectively.

User story:
When a user selects first input text field and clicks the list item, It should pass value from the selected list item to first input text field. 
and
When a user selects second input text field and clicks the list item, It should pass value from the selected list item to second input field.

Here is my code:  https://jsfiddle.net/shekhar123/uork6yhu/24/

```
<form action="/users" method="post">
  <div>
  <input type="text" id="firstInputField" palceholder="select the listitem" />
  <input type="text" id="secondtInputField" palceholder="select the list item" />
</div>
<h3>dynamic list item</h3>
<div>
    <ul class="list-group text-center" id="ulItem"></ul>
</div>


//Jquery file

var listItem = [{
    name: "name1"
   }, {
   name: "name2"
   }, {
   name: "name3"
}];
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var prop in listItem) {
    $("#ulItem").append('<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">' + listItem[prop].name + '</li>');
  }
});
```

I will be very thankful for your help and suggestion.

Comment: You need to explain how *user selects input **text** field*?  .. in your code you need `$("#firstInputField").val(listValue);` to set the value of button with clicked li attribute id .. Provide relevant Html,Js code

Answer (score 1):

The key is to set the a variable when one of the text fields gets the focus. The rest doesn't change. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/60jk6uk2/)

HTML:

```
<input id="input1" class="fields">
<input id="input2" class="fields">
<ul id="mylist">
  <li>1st value</li>
  <li>2nd value</li>
  <li>3rd value</li>
  <li>4th value</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
let selectedField = null;

$(".fields").on("focus", function() {selectedField = $(document.activeElement);});
$("#mylist li").on("click", function() {
  if (selectedField != null)
    selectedField.val($(this).html());
});
```

This is somewhat limited, especially if there are other inputs visible for which you then should reset the variable again when they get the focus. I personally would prefer dropdowns AKA comboboxes.

Comment: Excellent, I was missing the trick of the selected field, I tried focus, selected doesn't work. Thank you! great solution.